# TomEE 9.0.37 the bean encountered a non-application exception; Nested exception is: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException

Tags: java, jax-rs, apache-tomee

[2024-03-18 09:38:10,992] Artifact SpotitubeHerkansing:war: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.575 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.37
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.576 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Server built:          Jun 30 2020 20:09:49 UTC
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.576 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Server version number: 9.0.37.0
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.576 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke OS Name:               Windows 10
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.576 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke OS Version:            10.0
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.576 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Architecture:          amd64
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.576 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Java Home:             C:\Users\de Vries.jdks\openjdk-19.0.1
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.576 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke JVM Version:           19.0.1+10-21
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.576 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.576 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\de Vries\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.3\tomcat\20ec2741-5c7f-4cb1-a2b3-28831030b803
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.577 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\de Vries\Documents\HBO-ICT\DEA\tools\apache-tomee-plus-8.0.4
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.579 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.579 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.580 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.580 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\de Vries\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.3\tomcat\20ec2741-5c7f-4cb1-a2b3-28831030b803\conf\logging.properties
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.580 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.580 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Command line argument: -javaagent:C:\Users\de Vries\Documents\HBO-ICT\DEA\tools\apache-tomee-plus-8.0.4\lib\openejb-javaagent.jar
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.580 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.580 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.580 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.580 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=C:\Users\de Vries\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.3\tomcat\20ec2741-5c7f-4cb1-a2b3-28831030b803\jmxremote.password
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.580 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=C:\Users\de Vries\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.3\tomcat\20ec2741-5c7f-4cb1-a2b3-28831030b803\jmxremote.access
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.580 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.581 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Command line argument: -Dtomee.serialization.class.whitelist=
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.581 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Command line argument: -Dtomee.serialization.class.blacklist=-
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.581 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Command line argument: -Dtomee.remote.support=true
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.581 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Command line argument: -Dopenejb.system.apps=true
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.581 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.581 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.581 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.581 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\de Vries\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.3\tomcat\20ec2741-5c7f-4cb1-a2b3-28831030b803
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.581 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\de Vries\Documents\HBO-ICT\DEA\tools\apache-tomee-plus-8.0.4
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.581 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\de Vries\Documents\HBO-ICT\DEA\tools\apache-tomee-plus-8.0.4\temp
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.581 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Users\de Vries.jdks\openjdk-19.0.1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;c:\program files\oculus\support\oculus-runtime;c:\program files (x86)\razer\chromabroadcast\bin;c:\program files\razer\chromabroadcast\bin;c:\program files (x86)\common files\oracle\java\javapath;c:\program files (x86)\common files\acronis\virtualfile;c:\program files (x86)\common files\acronis\virtualfile64;c:\program files (x86)\common files\acronis\fileprotector;c:\program files (x86)\common files\acronis\fileprotector64;c:\program files (x86)\common files\acronis\snapapi;c:\program files\nvidia corporation\nvidia nvdlisr;c:\windows\system32;c:\windows;c:\windows\system32\wbem;c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0;c:\windows\system32\openssh;c:\program files\microsoft sql server\client sdk\odbc\170\tools\binn;c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sql server\150\tools\binn;c:\program files\microsoft sql server\150\tools\binn;c:\program files\microsoft sql server\150\dts\binn;c:\program files\dotnet;c:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\appdata\local\microsoft\windowsapps;c:\program files\git\cmd;c:\program files\nodejs;c:\program files\process lasso;c:\program files\docker\docker\resources\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Calibre2;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\de Vries\AppData\Roaming\local\bin;C:\Users\de Vries\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\de Vries\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\Users\de Vries\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\de Vries\Documents\HBO-ICT\JDK\jdk-14.0.2\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;C:\Users\de Vries\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\de Vries.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\de Vries\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\ghcup\bin;C:\Users\de Vries\AppData\Local\gitkraken\bin;C:\Users\de Vries.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2023.1.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DTS\Binn;;.]
18-Mar-2024 21:38:11.881 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.206 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog.info Using 'tomee.remote.support=true'
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.214 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog.info Using 'openejb.jdbc.datasource-creator=org.apache.tomee.jdbc.TomEEDataSourceCreator'
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.297 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance. ********************************************************************************
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.297 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance. OpenEJB http://tomee.apache.org/
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.297 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance. Startup: Mon Mar 18 21:38:12 CET 2024
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.297 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance. Copyright 1999-2018 (C) Apache OpenEJB Project, All Rights Reserved.
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.297 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance. Version: 8.0.4
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.297 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance. Build date: 20200722
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.298 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance. Build time: 12:23
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.298 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance. ********************************************************************************
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.298 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance. openejb.home = C:\Users\de Vries\Documents\HBO-ICT\DEA\tools\apache-tomee-plus-8.0.4
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.298 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance. openejb.base = C:\Users\de Vries\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.3\tomcat\20ec2741-5c7f-4cb1-a2b3-28831030b803
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.299 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.initializeOWB Created new singletonService org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@686449f9
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.301 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.initializeOWB Succeeded in installing singleton service
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.332 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.init TomEE configuration file is 'C:\Users\de Vries\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.3\tomcat\20ec2741-5c7f-4cb1-a2b3-28831030b803\conf\tomee.xml'
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.369 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=Tomcat Security Service, type=SecurityService, provider-id=Tomcat Security Service)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.371 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=Default Transaction Manager, type=TransactionManager, provider-id=Default Transaction Manager)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.373 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog.info Using 'openejb.system.apps=true'
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.376 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=Default Singleton Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Singleton Container)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.392 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating TransactionManager(id=Default Transaction Manager)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.443 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating SecurityService(id=Tomcat Security Service)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.469 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Container(id=Default Singleton Container)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.485 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Assembling app: openejb
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.545 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog.info Using 'openejb.jndiname.format={deploymentId}{interfaceType.openejbLegacyName}'
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.555 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder.bind Jndi(name=openejb/DeployerBusinessRemote) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.555 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder.bind Jndi(name=global/openejb/openejb/openejb/Deployer!org.apache.openejb.assembler.Deployer) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.556 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder.bind Jndi(name=global/openejb/openejb/openejb/Deployer) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.557 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder.bind Jndi(name=openejb/ConfigurationInfoBusinessRemote) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.557 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder.bind Jndi(name=global/openejb/openejb/openejb/Deployer!org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.cmd.ConfigurationInfo) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.560 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder.bind Jndi(name=MEJB) --> Ejb(deployment-id=MEJB)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.561 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder.bind Jndi(name=global/openejb/openejb/openejb/Deployer!javax.management.j2ee.ManagementHome) --> Ejb(deployment-id=MEJB)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.569 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Created Ejb(deployment-id=MEJB, ejb-name=openejb/Deployer, container=Default Singleton Container)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.571 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Created Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo, ejb-name=openejb/Deployer, container=Default Singleton Container)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.573 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Created Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer, ejb-name=openejb/Deployer, container=Default Singleton Container)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.573 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=MEJB, ejb-name=openejb/Deployer, container=Default Singleton Container)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.573 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo, ejb-name=openejb/Deployer, container=Default Singleton Container)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.573 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer, ejb-name=openejb/Deployer, container=Default Singleton Container)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.579 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.deployMBean Deployed MBean(openejb.user.mbeans:application=openejb,group=org.apache.openejb.assembler.monitoring,name=JMXDeployer)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.582 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Deployed Application(path=openejb)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.620 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.ServiceManager.initServer Creating ServerService(id=cxf)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.814 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.ServiceManager.initServer Creating ServerService(id=cxf-rs)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.861 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.start   ** Bound Services **
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.861 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.printRow   NAME                 IP              PORT
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.861 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.start -------
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.861 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.start Ready!
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.862 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Server initialization in [1487] milliseconds
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.887 INFO [main] org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBNamingContextListener.bindResource Importing a Tomcat Resource with id 'UserDatabase' of type 'org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase'.
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.887 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Resource(id=UserDatabase)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.900 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Starting service [Catalina]
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.900 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.37]
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.961 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setClassLoaderProperty Unable to set the web application class loader property [clearReferencesRmiTargets] to [true] as the property does not exist.
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.962 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setClassLoaderProperty Unable to set the web application class loader property [clearReferencesObjectStreamClassCaches] to [true] as the property does not exist.
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.962 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setClassLoaderProperty Unable to set the web application class loader property [clearReferencesObjectStreamClassCaches] to [true] as the property does not exist.
18-Mar-2024 21:38:12.962 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setClassLoaderProperty Unable to set the web application class loader property [clearReferencesThreadLocals] to [true] as the property does not exist.
18-Mar-2024 21:38:13.016 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
18-Mar-2024 21:38:13.027 INFO [main] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Server startup in [165] milliseconds
Mar 18, 2024 9:38:13 PM org.apache.openejb.client.EventLogger log
INFO: RemoteInitialContextCreated{providerUri=http://localhost:8080/tomee/ejb}
Connected to server
[2024-03-18 09:38:13,507] Artifact SpotitubeHerkansing:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
18-Mar-2024 21:38:13.686 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.openejb.util.JarExtractor.extract Extracting jar: C:\Users\de Vries\Documents\HBO-ICT\ASDP\SpotitubeHerkansing\spotitube\target\SpotitubeHerkansing.war
18-Mar-2024 21:38:14.192 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.openejb.util.JarExtractor.extract Extracted path: C:\Users\de Vries\Documents\HBO-ICT\ASDP\SpotitubeHerkansing\spotitube\target\SpotitubeHerkansing
18-Mar-2024 21:38:14.192 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWebApps using default host: localhost
18-Mar-2024 21:38:14.193 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.init ------------------------- localhost -> /SpotitubeHerkansing_war
18-Mar-2024 21:38:14.426 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.EjbTransactionUtil.handleSystemException EjbTransactionUtil.handleSystemException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.deployment.TomcatWebappDeployer.deploy(TomcatWebappDeployer.java:58)
at org.apache.openejb.assembler.DeployerEjb.deploy(DeployerEjb.java:177)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
at org.apache.openejb.security.internal.InternalSecurityInterceptor.invoke(InternalSecurityInterceptor.java:35)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:191)
at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:102)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonContainer._invoke(SingletonContainer.java:272)
at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonContainer.invoke(SingletonContainer.java:221)
at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.doEjbObject_BUSINESS_METHOD(EjbRequestHandler.java:371)
at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.processRequest(EjbRequestHandler.java:182)
at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.processEjbRequest(EjbDaemon.java:360)
at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.service(EjbDaemon.java:247)
at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbServer.service(EjbServer.java:104)
at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:60)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWar(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:658)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:598)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.deployment.TomcatWebappDeployer.deploy(TomcatWebappDeployer.java:47)
... 46 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SpotitubeHerkansing_war]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
... 51 more
Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to create annotation scanner for web module SpotitubeHerkansing_war: Unable to read class definition for org.han.dea.DAOs.ILoginDAO
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2363)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1198)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1131)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5044)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
... 52 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to create annotation scanner for web module SpotitubeHerkansing_war: Unable to read class definition for org.han.dea.DAOs.ILoginDAO
at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:886)
at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.load(DeploymentLoader.java:233)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2361)
... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read class definition for org.han.dea.DAOs.ILoginDAO
at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:1180)
at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.(AnnotationFinder.java:153)
at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.(AnnotationFinder.java:166)
at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory$OpenEJBAnnotationFinder.(FinderFactory.java:546)
at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.newFinder(FinderFactory.java:267)
at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.create(FinderFactory.java:80)
at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.createFinder(FinderFactory.java:69)
at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:878)
... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 63
at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:195)
at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:176)
at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:162)
at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:283)
at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:1176)
... 67 more
[2024-03-18 09:38:14,474] Artifact SpotitubeHerkansing:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2024-03-18 09:38:14,476] Artifact SpotitubeHerkansing:war: javax.ejb.EJBException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is:
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
18-Mar-2024 21:38:23.026 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\de Vries\Documents\HBO-ICT\DEA\tools\apache-tomee-plus-8.0.4\webapps\manager]
18-Mar-2024 21:38:23.030 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.init ------------------------- localhost -> /manager
18-Mar-2024 21:38:23.158 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication Configuring enterprise application: C:\Users\de Vries\Documents\HBO-ICT\DEA\tools\apache-tomee-plus-8.0.4\webapps\manager
18-Mar-2024 21:38:23.203 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder.build Enterprise application "C:\Users\de Vries\Documents\HBO-ICT\DEA\tools\apache-tomee-plus-8.0.4\webapps\manager" loaded.
18-Mar-2024 21:38:23.204 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Assembling app: C:\Users\de Vries\Documents\HBO-ICT\DEA\tools\apache-tomee-plus-8.0.4\webapps\manager
18-Mar-2024 21:38:23.344 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWebApps using context file C:\Users\de Vries\Documents\HBO-ICT\DEA\tools\apache-tomee-plus-8.0.4\webapps\manager\META-INF\context.xml
18-Mar-2024 21:38:23.346 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Deployed Application(path=C:\Users\de Vries\Documents\HBO-ICT\DEA\tools\apache-tomee-plus-8.0.4\webapps\manager)
18-Mar-2024 21:38:23.488 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.myfaces.ee.MyFacesContainerInitializer.onStartup Using org.apache.myfaces.ee.MyFacesContainerInitializer
18-Mar-2024 21:38:23.557 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
18-Mar-2024 21:38:23.620 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\de Vries\Documents\HBO-ICT\DEA\tools\apache-tomee-plus-8.0.4\webapps\manager] has finished in [594] ms

I'm attempting to run my program with TomEE 9.0.37. I get some references to being unable to read the class definition but haven't found any spelling errors or other issues. Does anyone have suggestions for me to try and resolve this error?

Comment: I've seen some long stack traces on here, but this is probably four times longer than the worst one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being caused by the Java SDK being too old. After updating the SDK to version 21, the issue was resolved.

Comment: comment can not be an answer